# Why scala native method can not be private

Tags: java, scala, java-native-interface, native, private

In Scala 2.11.0,

```
@native private def sampleMethod(argOne: Long): Int
```

Above declaration gives the following compiler error

> abstract member may not have private modifier
>     @native private def sampleMethod(argOne: Long): Int

What is the proper way of declaring native private member method

Comment: Note:

 `@native protected def sampleMethod(argOne Long): Int` compiles

 `@native private def sampleMethod(argOne: Long): Int = 0` compiles but doesn't  
 

    @native private def sampleMethod(argOne: Long): Int = _ gives following error

> unbound placeholder parameter
  @native private def sampleMethod(argOne: Long): Int = _

Comment: I don't see a valid reason. That's probably a bug.

Comment: The code samples you've provided won't compile without the @native annotation either.

Comment: @colinjwebb is correct , but what is the rational behind the error

Comment: Ordinarily, a subclass can't supply a private method overriding. Looks like a bug was introduced while refactoring that breaks the test for native methods, which get a pass. I commented on the ticket.

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily, a subclass can't supply an overriding private method, so private methods must not be abstract. Looks like a bug was introduced during a refactor that breaks the test for native methods, which get a pass. I commented on [the ticket](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9622?focusedCommentId=73809&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-73809), which is fixed for 2.12.